# Rendering a rotated texture in SDL that is in part offsceren

Tags: c++, math, sdl

I'm trying to render a texture that is partly offscreen and rotated. I have trouble determining src rectangle of a this rotated texture.

The naive approach that works if a texture is not rotated is this:

```
void CollisionObject::renderObject(SDL_Rect viewport)
{
    //dstrect is an object position + object max width / height

    if (not SDL_HasIntersection(&viewport, &dstrect))
        return;

    SDL_Rect src = physics::normalizedIntersection(dstrect, viewport); 
    SDL_Rect dest = physics::normalizedIntersection(viewport, dstrect);

    SDL_RenderCopyEx(gRenderer, texture, &src, &dest, body.getRotation(), NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
}

//helper function
SDL_Rect normalizedIntersection(SDL_Rect a, SDL_Rect b)
{
    int x = a.x;
    int y = a.y;

    a.x = 0;
    a.y = 0;
    b.x -= x;
    b.y -= y;

    SDL_Rect res;
    SDL_IntersectRect(&a, &b, &res);
    return res;
}
```

Unfortunately if the texture is rotated this is clearly wrong, as our src rectangle "cuts" the wrong part of the texture.

How can I determine the right src rectangle?

[Objects sticks out of top, so my intersection rectangle has y>0, which cuts the upper part of texture. This would be ok if the object was not rotated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haIZ4.png)

Answer (score 1):

SDL_Intersect wasn't returning negative values so if I had to render texture outside the viewport, (i.e. on top or left of camera), i wasnt calculating dest rectangle properly. This code fixed it:

```
void CollisionObject::renderObject(SDL_Rect viewport)
{
    if (not SDL_HasIntersection(&viewport, &dstrect))
        return;

    SDL_Rect dest = physics::normalizedIntersection(viewport, dstrect);

    // SDL_Intersect wont return -x or -y so we have to acoomodate for that

    if (dest.h < dstrect.h && dest.y <= 0)
    {
        dest.y -= (dstrect.h - dest.h);
    }
    if (dest.w < dstrect.w && dest.x <= 0)
    {
        dest.x -= (dstrect.w - dest.w);
    }
    dest.h = dstrect.h;
    dest.w = dstrect.w;

    SDL_RenderCopyEx(gRenderer, texture, NULL, &dest, body.getRotation(), NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
}
```